# Location of error icon

Tags: icon, error

Where is the location of the error and the warning icon?
I'm talking about the red octagon with a ! inside it and the yellow triangle also containing a !.

Example: http://www.askdavetaylor.com/1-blog-pics/mac-usb-device-removal-error.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/AlertStopIcon.icns`

Answer (score 1):

I remember that some system app had both icons in its application bundle, which you can open by dragging it to Preview.app.

A little note: Apple doesn't want you to use these icons as they are reserved for the system only.

---

You can find the Warning icon by dragging /System/Library/Core Services/Problem Reporter.app to Preview.app. Save the ICNS file as PNG and you're good to go — even though it's not a 512 × 512 image.

---

You can find a small error (32 × 32) icon at /Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DevToolsInterface.framework/Versions/A/Resources/XCBuildBadge-Error.png.